How can I watch a timelapse movie on the Nikon D7100?
How do I watch the Timelapse movie on my D7100?Aall I can see after the timelapse movie has finished are individual pictures. Does the D7100 not compile them in into a movie?

Just a note, some nikons, such as D600 can make the timelapse into a movie, automatically, and is viewable on the camera itself. This may or may not be an option on the D7100

You can't. AFAIK most (if not all) of the photo cameras (when have timelapse option) just take series of photos, based on the defined parameters. And after the camera has finished you should use some software to build a movie from individual frames.

But if you use PC software that came with the camera, this isn't always obvious - I'm sure I've seen Canon's assemble the frames into a timelapse automatically, but that might only be when shooting from the PC.

@ChrisH, I have not experience with timelapse on Canon. But if you shoot tethering again software on PC build the movie (if this is obvious or not is another story). And in camera you have only frames. The only case I know Canon "build" in camera is when shoot HDR and you have in camera source photos (JPEG or RAW) and HDR resulting image.


Does the D7100 not compile them in into a movie?

No. The time-lapse movie settings are under the photo shooting menu. The camera is not in movie mode, nor is it initiated with the record video button.
Time-lapse movie is really what is called "interval timer shooting" in most other Nikons that have that capability... it has nothing to do with movies per se.
